# No meromorphic function dominates another meromorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, meromorphic-functions

It is well known that  "genuinely different" entire functions cannot dominate each other. More precisely, let $f$ and $g$  be entire functions in $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying 
$|f(z)|\le |g(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}.$
Then $f=Cg$ for some $C\in \mathbb{C}.$

I'd like to know the result for meromorphic functions similar to the above result for entire functions.

Please let me know if you have any comment about this question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GuidoA. Read the question again.  0876 knows the result for entire functions, and asks whether there is a similar result for meromorphic functions.

Comment: Oh, totally misread that, my bad. Never mind then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are meromorphic in $\mathbb C$ with $|f(z)| \le |g(z)|$, then $f(z)/g(z)$ is meromorphic and bounded.  Thus its singularities are all removable; after removing them, you have a bounded entire function which Liouville says is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same result holds for meromorphic functions: if $f$ and $g$ are meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $|f(z)|\leq |g(z)|$ for all $z$, then $f(z)=Cg(z)$ for some constant $C$.  The proof is also basically the same: consider the function $h(z)=g(z)/f(z)$.  This function $h$ is meromorphic, and $|h(z)|\leq 1$ for any $z$ except possibly the poles or zeroes of $g$.  But the poles and zeroes of $g$ are isolated, and so by continuity $|h(z)|\leq 1$ everywhere and in particular $h$ has no poles.  Since $h$ is an entire bounded function, it is constant.